# How to import a module for all functions?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a main file, called 'main.py' and two subfolders. One is called 'externals' and contains 'easygui.py' and the other one is called 'modules' and contains a file called 'gui.py'.

The program is started via main.py

I import easygui in main.py with `import externals.easygui`. The same way I import modules.gui

But when I call the welcome-function, It does not know easygui, I have to import it in the function. As I want to call more easygui-functions, I don't want to import easygui in every def.

How can this be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Steffen

Examples (for readability without try/except and comment stuff):

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import externals.easygui
import modules.gui

main():
    gui.welcome()
```

gui.py:

```
def welcome():
    msgbox("Welcome!", ok_button="Ok")
```

Comment: It's bit confusing where all your functions are coming from (where is msgbox meant to be coming from). And you talk of welcome being in gui.py and then say it's in a file called welcome.py. I think you need to re-read your question and edit it appropriately.

Comment: True. In the code examples was an naming error. It is gui.py. welcome() is in gui.py. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `welcome` is in `easygui.py`, you want:

```
def main():
   externals.easygui.welcome()
```

As these things can get tedious to type, it's often customary to import subpackages under an abbreviated name:

```
import externals.easygui as eg
def main():
    eg.welcome()
```

Alternatively, if you can make the whole thing a package by adding `__init__.py`, and then you can control the namespace which gets imported from there ...

---

As far as sideways imports go, here's a test directory structure I set up:

```
steffen
  |- __init__.py
  |- main.py
  |- easygui
     |- __init__.py
     |- gui.py
  |- external
     |- __init__.py
     |- welcome.py
```

Now, (for simplicity) each `__init__.py` simply imports the files/modules contained in that directory.  So, in steffen:

```
#steffen.__init__.py
import main
import easygui
import external
```

and in external

```
#steffen/external/__init__.py
import welcome
```

and so forth.

for the actual code:

**main.py:**

```
import easygui
def main():
    easygui.gui.welcome()
```

**easygui/gui.py:**

```
import steffen.external as se
def welcome():
    se.welcome.hello()
```

**external/welcome.py**

```
def hello():
    print "Hello"
```

Now I can use all of this.  In the parent directory of steffen (just to make sure the package steffen is on PYTHONPATH), I can:

```
import steffen
steffen.main.main()
```

Phew!  Now, it's a little silly to have `steffen.main.main()`.  If you want to refer to the function as just `steffen.main()`, you can set that up in `steffen.__init__.py`.  Just change it to:

```
#steffen.__init__.py
from main import main
import easygui
import external
```

So, if you would call a function by `foo.func()` in `__init__.py`, you'll call it as `steffen.foo.func()` in a script that imports `steffen`.  Likewise, if you would call the function as `foo()` in `__init__.py`, you'll call it as `steffen.foo()` in a script that imports steffen.  Hopefully that makes sense.  There's a lot to digest in this simplest working example I could come up with.  The upside, if you can work through all of this and understand it, then you know almost everything there is to know about writing python packages (we haven't talked about relative imports which could be used here too, or about writing a `setup.py` to actually install your package, but those are fairly easy to understand once you understand this stuff).

Comment: welcome() is in gui, not in easygui. There are two different folders with two different py-files.

Comment: @Steffen -- So you're saying that files in the `modules` directory depend on files in the `externals` directory?

Comment: @Steffen -- Not necessarily -- but you'll need to make them packages.  Let me try to hack something together to demonstrate

Comment: @Steffen -- Demonstration finished.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I gave it a try and it does not work -yet! Maybe I missed something. But one correction: `import SOMETHING.py` does not work. My interpreter tries to import `SOMETHING` and `py`. So its seems that it concatenates the modules with `.`

Comment: @Steffen -- Sorry.  it should just be `import SOMETHING`, not `import SOMETHING.py`.  Brain error when I was copying everything over.

Comment: Ah, got it! My program has much more folders and dependencies. I over-simplified my example and made an error. It works now! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Steffen -- Happy to help.  Package dependencies was something that I had a difficult time groking when I started.  Hopefully this answer will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Each source file needs to have its own imports, as they do not know about the imports of other modules. You must include an `import externals.easygui` in `modules.gui.py` at the top of the file.

eg. gui.py

```
from externals.easygui import msgbox

def welcome():
    msgbox("Welcome!", ok_button="Ok")
```

Comment: Ok, that's the way I'm doing it right now. I thought there might be a way to do a global import.

Comment: I know of no programming language that allows global imports that apply to all modules/classes. Nor do I think there should be. What you suggest would mean that gui.py doesn't even know its own dependencies.

Comment: Nope. I thought of a way of importing described above by @mgilson

Comment: I don't really see how that answers your question. gui.py still knows it's dependencies. It depends on __init__.py which depends on the relevant module.

Answer (score 0):

## What we have here...

Import the gui.py module and give it the name gui, so that you just have to use gui label to access to the functions in gui.

In the gui.py module import only the function msgbox, so that you don't have no other stuff imported (as you wanted this).

Now, when the program runs it shows the message calling the gui.welcome function.

## main.py

```
import modules.gui as gui

def main():
    gui.welcome()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## gui.py in subfolder modules

```
from externals.easygui import msgbox

def welcome():
    msgbox("Welcome!", ok_button = "Ok")
```